# HTML Form POST to PHP Script not working

Tags: php, html

Ok, so I've been writing PHP code for a little while and understand it pretty well, but this has me stumped.

// PHP file

```
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state_province = $_POST['state_province'];
$postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
$productid = $_POST['productid'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
echo $country;
echo 'Script is fine';
```

//html file

```
    <form id="quick-quote-form" class="jquery" name='quick-quote-form' action='php/quick-quote.php' method='POST'>

        <label for="country">Country</label>

            <select name="country" id="country">
                <option selected="" value="">-- Select a Country --</option>

                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>

                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            </select><br />

        <span class="state">

        <label for="state">State</label>

            <select name="state_province" id="state_province">
                <option value="">-- Select a State --</option>

                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>

                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>

            </select>
            </span><br />

      <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label><input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code" required><br />

        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"><br />

        <input name="productid" id="productid" type="hidden" value="xxxxx">

        <input type="submit" value="Go">

    </form>
```

When I post this, the country var and any of the other variables come out empty. I just switched hosts and it seemed to have stopped working then. Is there some kind of host setting that could be preventing this from working, or is there something blatantly wrong with my simple code that I'm blind to?

Firebug shows the posted values fine when I submit with AJAX, but there is no successful response.

Someone, please, prove me wrong or give me the magic switch in my CPanel to make it all better!

Thanks!

edit: phpinfo(); returns

```
PHP Version 5.2.14

System  Linux mole.arvixe.com 2.6.18-294.8.1.el5.lve0.7.33.1 #1 SMP Sat Sep 18 17:12:09 EEST 2010 x86_64
Build Date  Aug 3 2010 10:12:11
Configure Command    './configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-ttf' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /home/davekiss/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20041225
PHP Extension   20060613
Zend Extension  220060519
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, data, http, ftp
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed

 This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies

PHP Credits
Configuration
PHP Core
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  On  On
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   error_log   error_log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 6135    6135
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php   .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
max_execution_time  0   0
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  600 600
memory_limit    256M    256M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   3000M   3000M
precision   12  12
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  On  On
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 3000M   3000M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off Off

bcmath
BCMath support  enabled

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

cgi-fcgi
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.logging 1   1

ctype
ctype functions enabled

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2010.9
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    America/Detroit

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   America/Detroit America/Detroit

dom
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.7.6
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled

exif
EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: exif.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Revision: 298196 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support enabled

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.2.1
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
XBM Support enabled

gettext
GetText Support enabled

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru gost adler32 crc32 crc32b haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

imagick
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  2.2.2
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.4.8 2010-07-25 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2010-07-25
ImageMagick Number of supported formats:    191
ImageMagick Supported formats   A, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, BRG, C, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GBR, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRB, HISTOGRAM, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, JNG, JPEG, JPG, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RBG, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Directive   Local Value Master Value
imagick.locale_fix  0   0
imagick.progress_monitor    0   0

imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
SSL Support enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Version  2.7.6
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 4.4.4
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check On

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   20060101

mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.0.91
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    no value    no value
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.0.91
Client API header version   5.0.91
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Version OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.02 2010-03-19

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    100000  100000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers sqlite, sqlite2, mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version    5.0.91

pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
PECL Module version (bundled) 1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $
SQLite Library  3.3.7

pgsql
PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   8.1.21
Multibyte character support enabled
SSL support enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited

posix
Revision    $Revision: 293036 $

pspell
PSpell Support  enabled

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: php_reflection.c 300129 2010-06-03 00:43:37Z felipe $

session
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Revision: 299016 $
Schema support  enabled

sockets
Sockets Support enabled

SourceGuardian
SourceGuardian Loader Support   enabled
SourceGuardian Loader Version   8.2
SourceGuardian Loader Build Number  0x00000011
phpSHIELD Support   enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sourceguardian.restrict_unencoded   0   0

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilterIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SimpleXMLIterator, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplObjectStorage, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

SQLite
SQLite support  enabled
PECL Module version 2.0-dev $Id: sqlite.c 298697 2010-04-28 12:10:10Z iliaa $
SQLite Library  2.8.17
SQLite Encoding iso8859

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite.assoc_case   0   0

standard
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled
Dynamic Library Support enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars  PHP_    PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars    LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=    a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=
user_agent  no value    no value

tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx
WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer enabled

xml
XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
EXPAT Version   expat_1.95.8

xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled

xmlrpc
core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version   0.51
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by Epinions.com

xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled

xsl
XSL enabled
libxslt Version 1.1.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version 2.7.6
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.26

Zend Optimizer
Optimization Pass 1 enabled
Optimization Pass 2 enabled
Optimization Pass 3 enabled
Optimization Pass 4 enabled
Optimization Pass 9 enabled
Zend Loader enabled
License Path    no value
Obfuscation level   3

zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.3
Linked Version  1.2.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules
Module Name
ionCube Loader

Environment
Variable    Value
CONTENT_LENGTH  84
CONTENT_TYPE    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/davekiss/public_html
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-us
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_COOKIE __utma=185750460.516135541.1265907149.1265907149.1265907149.1; cprelogin=no; cpsession=asKpSrAbEDp4YgxoTDNjdLn17iwC86ERsoUcKLHDXMwojSdHTeND67uw_; logintheme=cpanel
HTTP_HOST   davekiss.com
HTTP_ORIGIN http://davekiss.com
HTTP_REFERER    http://davekiss.com/
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH   XMLHttpRequest
PATH    /bin:/usr/bin
PHPRC   /home/davekiss
PHP_AUTH_PW xxxxxxx
PHP_AUTH_USER   xxxxxx
QUERY_STRING    no value
REDIRECT_STATUS 200
REMOTE_ADDR 76.205.121.33
REMOTE_PORT 54915
REQUEST_METHOD  POST
SERVER_ADDR 174.121.43.195
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@davekiss.com
SERVER_NAME davekiss.com
SERVER_PORT 80
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28 Server at davekiss.com Port 80</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28

PHP Variables
Variable    Value
_REQUEST["__utma"]  185750460.516135541.1265907149.1265907149.1265907149.1
_REQUEST["cprelogin"]   no
_REQUEST["cpsession"]   asKpSrAbEDp4YgxoTDNjdLn17iwC9Ij3OFU86ERsoUcKLHDXMwojSdHTeND67uw_
_REQUEST["logintheme"]  cpanel
_COOKIE["__utma"]   185750460.516135541.1265907149.1265907149.1265907149.1
_COOKIE["cprelogin"]    no
_COOKIE["cpsession"]    asKpSrAbEDp4YgxoTDNjdLn17iwC9Ij3OFU86ERsoUcKLHDXMwojSdHTeND67uw_
_COOKIE["logintheme"]   cpanel
_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]   84
_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/davekiss/public_html
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  */*
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-us
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   max-age=0
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]  __utma=185750460.516135541.1265907149.1265907149.1265907149.1; cprelogin=no; cpsession=asKpSrAbEDp4YgxoTDNjdLn17iwC9Ij3OFU86ERsoUcKLHDXMwojSdHTeND67uw_; logintheme=cpanel
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    davekiss.com
_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]  http://davekiss.com
_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] http://davekiss.com/
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8
_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]    XMLHttpRequest
_SERVER["PATH"] /bin:/usr/bin
_SERVER["PHPRC"]    /home/davekiss
_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]  xxxxxxx
_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]    xxxxxxx
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]  200
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  76.205.221.33
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  54915
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   POST
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /php/quick-quote.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /home/davekiss/public_html/php/quick-quote.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /php/quick-quote.php
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  174.121.43.195
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@davekiss.com
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  davekiss.com
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28 Server at davekiss.com Port 80</address>
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /burnpost/php/quick-quote.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1287179383
_SERVER["argv"] 
Array
(
)
_SERVER["argc"] 0
_ENV["CONTENT_LENGTH"]  84
_ENV["CONTENT_TYPE"]    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]   /home/davekiss/public_html
_ENV["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]   CGI/1.1
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT"] */*
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]    gzip, deflate
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]    en-us
_ENV["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]  max-age=0
_ENV["HTTP_CONNECTION"] keep-alive
_ENV["HTTP_COOKIE"] __utma=185750460.516135541.1265907149.1265907149.1265907149.1; cprelogin=no; cpsession=asKpSrAbEDp4YgxoTDNjdLn17iwC9Ij3OFU86ERsoUcKLHDXMwojSdHTeND67uw_; logintheme=cpanel
_ENV["HTTP_HOST"]   davekiss.com
_ENV["HTTP_ORIGIN"] http://davekiss.com
_ENV["HTTP_REFERER"]    http://davekiss.com/
_ENV["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8
_ENV["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]   XMLHttpRequest
_ENV["PATH"]    /bin:/usr/bin
_ENV["PHPRC"]   /home/davekiss
_ENV["PHP_AUTH_PW"]xxxxxx
_ENV["PHP_AUTH_USER"]   xxxxxxxxxxxxx
_ENV["QUERY_STRING"]    no value
_ENV["REDIRECT_STATUS"] 200
_ENV["REMOTE_ADDR"] 76.205.121.33
_ENV["REMOTE_PORT"] 54915
_ENV["REQUEST_METHOD"]  POST
_ENV["REQUEST_URI"] /php/quick-quote.php
_ENV["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] /home/davekiss/public_html/burnpost/php/quick-quote.php
_ENV["SCRIPT_NAME"] /php/quick-quote.php
_ENV["SERVER_ADDR"] 174.121.43.195
_ENV["SERVER_ADMIN"]    webmaster@davekiss.com
_ENV["SERVER_NAME"] davekiss.com
_ENV["SERVER_PORT"] 80
_ENV["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] HTTP/1.1
_ENV["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]    <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28 Server at davekiss.com Port 80</address>
_ENV["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.28
```

Comment: on the php side, write `print_r( $_POST );` and print the results here please.

Comment: Array ( ) is the result (I have a session open in my script as well, irrelevent to the problem.)

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with the poster below and ask for you to do <?php phpinfo(); ?>; so that we can see the result.

Comment: Updated the question with this info.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the attribute `selected=""` is the same thing as `selected="selected"`. Obviously there are other problems at work here, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

I had my post_max_filesize directive set so high (3000) that it was rolling the integer datatype over to a negative value. I corrected this by setting my php.ini's post_max_filesize to 128M.

Thanks to all that offered their help!

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is not with the code you posted. I moved it to a testing server and what you posted worked just fine.

A couple of things to try:

- Where are you printing the values? If you are doing this first thing on the page (and the values go before the <html> tag), then they may not get rendered. Do a view source to be sure that the values are not getting posted.
- Inspect the Request using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This will tell you what is actually being sent down the wire to your PHP script.

Past that, there's not much I can say without seeing more code.

Comment: I'm actually sending the variables to another script with cURL, but I've eliminated this step just to remove any extra possibilities of this not working. I have a jquery script set up to print the response of the script into a div, and I'm getting the string that is echoed manually but not the variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working on OSX so fiddler isn't an option, but firebug shows the string key and value being posted normally.

Comment: @Dave Kiss, in that case, Wireshark. It does the same, only more.