# How to change the value of HTML tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am making an email form, but I want to convert the value (I have it in numbers to calculate price) in an html tag to a word or phrase in PHP.

```html
Toppings:
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="0">Cheese +$0</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="ba" value="4">Bacon +$4</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="ha" value="5">Ham +$5</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="to" value="1">Tomato +$1</input>
```

```html
  $all=
"email: ".$email."\r\
".
"subject: ".$subject."\r\
".
"referer: ".$name."\r\
".
"message: ".$address."\r\
".
"phone: ".$lg." ".$md." ".$sm."\r\
".
"phone: ".$cheese." ".$bacon." ".$ham." ".$tomato."\r\
".
"phone: ".$phone."\r\
";
```

This will send me an email with the value. I want it to send an email with the name or whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Form POST to PHP Script not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946359/html-form-post-to-php-script-not-working)

Comment: No, this is all working. I just want to know how I can have the name of the tag instead of the value.

Comment: So you are saying you want to send something like "ch" or "ba" instead of the value which is "0" or "4"?

Comment: Yes,  but I also need the numbers so I can't change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the value to "0-cheese" or "4-bacon"? That way both the numbers and the word/phrase you want is included in the email.

If you want the script to only isolate the numbers, you can use a `preg_match_all` function like so:

```
$str = 'In My Cart : 6 items';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

Where `$str` is the value of the input selected.